# Is there any method called setUserId(string userId) in firebase_admob flutter plugin?

Tags: flutter

I have integrated the firebase_admob sdk using the plugin at: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/firebase_admob

I'm using the RewardedVideo in my flutter app. There's a method to set the user Id in RewardedVideo, as mentioned in the following link: 
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/reward/RewardedVideoAd.html#setUserId(java.lang.String)

I want to know how to set the user Id. Because, I couldn't find the method setUserId(String userId) in the plugin. Is there any alternative way to achieve this functionality?

I will be thankful for the solution.

Comment: Did you mean test ID for device?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is available at:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33033

Hope this helps!